Copy and paste if the cell value starts with certain letter
In Column A, there is data which contain question, choices and other data. The choices starts with A B C D in each row. I just need to copy the CHOICES and QUESTION  and paste into next Column B. Sample data as shown below.
I tried the below code, but it copies only the choices no the question whihc is above choice A. I need help to fix the code. Also this code runs slowly.



ColA
ColB




Program Math



Exercise 3-24



This is a sample test



Select the correct answer



1 Question
1 Question


A choice-1
A choice-1


B choice-2
B choice-2


C choice-3
C choice-3


D choice-4
D choice-4


Program Math



Exercise 5-12



This is a sample test



Select the correct answer



2 Question
2 Question


A choice-1
A choice-1


B choice-2
B choice-2


C choice-3
C choice-3


D choice-4
D choice-4


Program Math



Exercise 2-14



This is a sample test



Select the correct answer



1 Question



A choice-1



B choice-2



C choice-3



D choice-4




Sub CopyPasteChoices()

Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

Sheet2.Activate

For Each a In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If a.Value Like "A *" Then
        a.Copy Destination:=a.Offset(0, 2)
    End If
Next a

For Each b In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If b.Value Like "B *" Then
        b.Copy Destination:=b.Offset(0, 2)
    End If
Next b

For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If c.Value Like "C *" Then
        c.Copy Destination:=c.Offset(0, 2)
    End If
Next c

For Each d In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If d.Value Like "D *" Then
        d.Copy Destination:=d.Offset(0, 2)
    End If
Next d

End Sub


Could you explain what the result should look like? Like column B without the empty rows or something else?

I tried to workout the code as shown above. Seeking help in the code to copy question.

You can combine the criterias into one loop with including the check for the Question. This will also speed up the execution.
Sub CopyPasteChoices()

Dim a As Range

Sheet2.Activate

For Each a In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If a.Value Like "A *" Then a.Offset(-1).Copy Destination:=a.Offset(-1, 2)
    If a.Value Like "A *" Or a.Value Like "B *" Or a.Value Like "C *" Or a.Value Like "D *" Then
        a.Copy Destination:=a.Offset(0, 2)
    End If
Next a


End Sub

